# R can't import the hexadecimal data

Tags: r, shiny

This is an extract code from the program I'm writing.

```
data2 <- reactive({
        print("in reactive data in moudle iv testing")
        if(input$type2 == "Singapore") {

          tbl.name2 <-paste("outdoor_module_iv_testing")
          tm <- paste(input$date2,input$time2)
          site2 <- paste("3")
          moduleid <- paste(input$moduleid)
          print(tm)
          data2 <- db.read2(tbl.name2, par= "*",tm,site2,moduleid)
             lol <- (data2$iv_file)
        print(lol)

        }
```

The function db.read2 is defined in another "DButil.R" file so don't worry about it. 
As you can see, I want to extract the 'iv_file' column from the database. Which is has long hexadecimal data like,

```
[1] NUL
[2] NUL
[3] NUL 
[4] NUL
[5] NUL
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
```

But the print file I get for this iv_file column is ,

```
[1] "\\x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[2] "\\x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[3] "\\x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[4] "\\x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[5] "\\x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[6] "\\x3031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030303130303030303030313030303030303031303030303030"
```

Why doesn't it import the actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the end of your hex value in row[6]. It has an '\'' character at the end of line. Further, hex C (or 12) is read/written like `0xC`.

If the value in row[6] is just one value you can just read it by: `as.numeric(paste('0x',your_value, sep='')`

Your Value will be inf.

By the way: The `paste`-command in line `tbl.name2 <-paste("outdoor_module_iv_testing")` seems to be unnecessary. You should also start giving your variables reasonable names.